# Finding the first vertex in a recursively growing graph

Tags: graphs, probability-theory

I have an undirected graph which grew according to a **recursive algorithm**, i.e., it started with a single vertex and then, one after another, new vertices arrived and connected to existing ones.

Now, I'm given the graph with, say, $n$ vertices. **I would like to estimate (efficiently) which vertex was the first one.** How can I do so? Note that this is, in most cases, a probabilistic question. This means that you cannot determine the first vertex but you can give an answer which is the most probable vertex.

---

I am already aware of an algorithm by Shah & Zaman (2011) from [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5961801). However in this paper, they assume that the graph of interest (in their case the rumor graph) is actually a tree. In my case however, this is *not* the case.

---

**Requirements to the graph growing algorithm:**

- In each step, only one vertex is added.
- Vertices from previous steps are *not* regarded differently. This means that when a new vertex arrives, it does not have any information on the timing the previous vertices were added.

Comment: You can assume that the graph is undirected. I will update the question shortly.

Comment: Every vertex is equally likely to be the first vertex. Can you please explain why this not the case?

Comment: This is not generally the case. For example consider a line graph (u -- v -- w). Then, it is double as likely that v was the first vertex than either u or w. Should I elaborate further?

Comment: As mentioned, the given graph grew according to a recursive algorithm. Therefore, one of the vertices was added last. This can be either $u$ or $w$. $v$ cannot be the last added vertex because then $u$ and $w$ would be left without any attachment. This means the second-step graph looks either like u -- v or v -- w. Using the same logic, the first-step graph looks like u or v or v or w (those are four distinct representations). In this representation, $v$ appears twice as often as either $u$ or $w$. Is this more clear?

Comment: By recursive do you mean as per DFS/BSF algorithm? Also, I did not understand how the algorithm chooses the first vertex. It should be independent of if the algorithm is recursive or not, since it is the first step of the algorithm.

Also, please edit your question instead of leaving the explanation in comments since it would be difficult for the future visitors to follow. :)

Comment: Your example with the path graph u-v-w and conclusion "it is double as likely that v was the first vertex than either u or w" is incorrect in general. It depends on what assumptions you have on the "recursive algorithm" that was used to grow the graph.

Comment: For instance, if the algorithm is guaranteed to add only one vertex, and only to vertices from the previous generation, then the first vertex must be u or w, and cannot be v. Alternatively is the algorithm is guaranteed to add two vertex to every vertex, then the first vertex must be v and cannot be u or w. In both cases, it would be incorrect to say that v is twice as likely to be the first vertex.

Comment: Thank you for this important insight @Stef . This totally makes sense. In my case, I am looking at graph growing algorithms (which I cannot clearly define at the moment) where both of the cases you describe would not be possible. I'll try to update the question accordingly.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but assuming that at every iteration, one existing vertex is chosen uniformly at random, and a new vertex is added as a neighbour to this vertex, then the expected number of neighbours of a vertex added $n$ iterations ago is $\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$, which is a strictly increasing function of $n$. So you could just pick the vertex that has the most neighbours, and it's the most likely to be the first one. Although if that is really the growing algorithm, then the graph is guaranteed to be a tree, which you said is not your case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the first node is the one and only one in the graph having only outgoing edges. (If no such node exists, there is no solution.)

If all you have is the graph topology (which representation ?), all you can do is an exhaustive search node by node until you find one with only outgoing edges.

If the graph is a DAG, you can trace a backward path from an arbitrary node. But in the worst case this is not faster than exhaustive.

Comment: The question specifically mentions that the graph is undirected.

Comment: @Stef: this makes no sense. Even in a trivial graph of two nodes you couldn't tell which is the first.

Comment: The question is lacking details, yes. But depending on the exact growing algorithm this could be a probabilistic problem. For instance, a vertex which has a high degree could be more likely to be an old vertex, and a vertex with a low degree could be more likely to be a recently-added vertex.

Comment: @Stef: I will not go into such conjectures. The OP needs to fix the question.